# Regular expression only 2 consecutive specific characters

Tags: regex, abstraction

I'm trying to build a regular expression for an abstract filesystem. It should:

- Start with letters [a-zA-Z], '/', or '.'
- Only allow one consecutive occurrence of '/'
- Only allow two consecutive occurrences of '.'

Here's what I have so far (works not allowing 3 '.'s but works when typing only one. Any input is greatly appreciated. I tried positive and negative lookaheads for the second group but it still has the same problem.

```
(?!.*\/{2})(?!.*\.{3})^[A-Za-z\/\.]*$
```

My Regex101 link:

https://regex101.com/r/xM8oY5/1

Comment: Why are you trying to express all conditions in a singular regular expression instead of building a regex for each rule? How about disallowing `/^[^/.a-z]/i`, `/[/]{2,}/` and `/[.]{3,}/` in seperate tests?

Comment: Good suggestion! i could do a preg_match() in php as many times as I needed to. I hadn't thought of it. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added a negative lookahead, that matches a dot `.` surrounded by two not-dot characters.

```
/(?!(.*[^.])?\.([^.].*)?$)(?!.*\/{2})(?!.*\.{3})^[A-Za-z\/\.]*$/
 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    (.*[^.])?              -> some arbitrary characters and at least one not-dot
             \.            -> the dot
               ([^.].*)?$  -> one not-dot and some arbitrary characters
```

Both blocks - before and after the dot - are optional, if the single dot comes at start or end of the string.

Test it on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/xM8oY5/2).